# Replacing only the captured group using re.sub and multiple replacements

Tags: python, regex

Below is just a simple example I've created.

```
string = 'I love sleeping. I love singing. I love dancing.'
pattern =re.compile(r'I love (\w+)\.')
```

I want to just replace the (\w+) portion with re.sub.
This question is in two parts:

I want to replace (\w+), without having to resort to groups
to capture the rest of the text.

So I don't want to do something like:

```
pattern =re.compile(r'(I) (love) (\w+)\.')
re.sub(pattern, r'/1 /2 swimming', string)
```

because this may be unreliable when working with huge amounts of text and
optional groups.

Second part:

Since I will have three matches, is it possible to feed in a list with re.sub that will iterate through the list for each match and make the sub
accordingly. In another words, 
I want each item of the list `['Swimming, Eating, Jogging']` to sync with the
matches, (like the method zip) and make the substitution.

So the output should be something like this (even a single total output is fine:

```
'I love Swimming'
'I love Eating'
'I love Jogging'
```

Comment: why would you capture things separately instead of `r'(I love )\w+\.'` and what doesn't work about it for your use case? for the second couldn't you just split on period?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind and lookahead based regex and then a `lambda` function to iterate through replacements words:

```
>>> words = ['Swimming', 'Eating', 'Jogging']
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=I love )\w+(?=\.)')
>>> print pattern.sub(lambda m: words.pop(0), string)
'I love Swimming. I love Eating. I love Jogging.'
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/Zsi8vJ)

Comment: Wow, so concise. I'm going to play around with the code and see if I have any questions.

Comment: Thank you. It seems turn-arounds don't work with a variable-width size right?  Meaning -- I can't use quantifiers within the group I want to use turn-arounds. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: Look ahead works fine with variable width but look behind doesn't.